# TYPO3: Remove validation from ObjectStorage property in model

Tags: typo3, extbase

Does anyone knows if it is possible to remove recursive validation from model in extbase TYPO3?

Let's say I have model with following properties:

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @validate NotEmpty
 */
protected $title;

/**
 * @var string
 * @validate NotEmpty
 */
protected $city;

 /**
 * @lazy
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<my/model/classname>
 */
protected $categories;
```

When passing my object to controller action I want only title and city to be validated. I would like categories not to be validated. Extbase is validating all relations in ObjectStorage recursively - so if my/model/classname has also another ObjectStorage relations they will be validated too.

Comment: I have the same problem. Someone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is similar thread from TYPO3 forum https://forum.typo3.org/index.php/t/204874/-typo3-mvc-disable-recursive-validation-objectstorage