# typo3 skip ObjectStorage recursive validation

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-8.x

I have typo3 version 8.7.17

I have model BookedDate, with property availableDate with link to parent model. AvailableDate model has ObjectStorage property BookedDates.

My validation broken, because there is recursive validation. I don't need it. I have read a lot of similar problem but didn't find good solution or anything that works for me.

I tried it and different variants with property paths:

```
   $this->arguments->getArgument($book)
        ->getPropertyMappingConfiguration()
        ->forProperty('date.bookedDates.*')
        ->skipProperties('bookedDate');
```

I need skip validation for BookedDate.date.bookedDates

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem but no one has replied anything too.
[TYPO3: Remove validation from ObjectStorage property in model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50876032/typo3-remove-validation-from-objectstorage-property-in-model)

So far I was able to remove validation from single relations property by custom function:

```
public function removePropertyValidation($argument, $property)
    {
        if ($this->arguments->hasArgument($argument)) {
            /** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Validation\Validator\ConjunctionValidator */
            $conjunctionValidator = $this->arguments->getArgument($argument)->getValidator();
            //get all validators for argument
            foreach ($conjunctionValidator->getValidators() as $validator) {
                if ($validator instanceof ConjunctionValidator) {
                    foreach ($validator->getValidators() as $validators) {
                        //get all validators for property
                        if ($validators instanceof GenericObjectValidator) {
                            foreach ($validators->getPropertyValidators($property) as $propertyValidator) {
                                //remove only standard validator
                                if ($propertyValidator instanceof ConjunctionValidator) {
                                    foreach ($propertyValidator->getValidators() as $valid) {
                                        $propertyValidator->removeValidator($valid);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in your initializeAction add:

```
$this->removePropertyValidation('book', 'date');
```

Comment: Thank u for code. But it doesn't work for me. I have some object BookedDate, this object has diff properties, also property AvailableDate. I need to validate all BookedDate properties, but I don't need to validate properties of BookedDate properties.